# “Inside” vs. “on the inside”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

What is the difference between usage of *inside* and *on the inside*?

For instance is there any difference in the following phrases:

1. condensation **on the**  inside **of** the window
2. condensation                inside the window

Maybe there are some situations where I can’t interchange them?

EDIT:

Brain comments helps a lot to understand the difference. I'll add one more example for clarification, please correct me if I'm wrong.

1. Cameras will be on the inside the room
2. Cameras will be inside the room

First example means that cameras are going to be fixed on the walls inside the room, the second tells that they are going to be inside rooms, but can be just standing on a leg.

Comment: Why would you use *of* at all in number two?

Comment: Some thing have an "inner" suface—a window pane, for example, has a surface that faces outward, and a surface that faces inward. They have an inside (ie, the "in" side) and an outside (ie, the "out" side).  So it makes sense to say _the inside of_  a window. Other things (e.g. an apple) have an "inside" that is entirely contained in the thing. The inside of an apple is everything but the skin. With a person, one speaks of "insides" (plural) as meaning one's guts, or all internal organs.

Comment: As for the double-pane window I mentioned in a comment below (or triple-pane windows), we really don't have a good non-technical term for the space(s) _between_  the panes, other than _gap(s)_ , which doesn't really describe it.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock thanks for clarification. Could you please check my update in question and say if I understood it correctly?

Comment: Not quite. For the first "camera" example, if they are fixed to the walls, you would say they are _mounted on the walls of_ the room. "room" is different from "window"—a room doesn't have an "outside", and "inside of the room" does not imply "on the walls". The second "camera" sentence could be more simply put: Cameras will be **in** the room.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock thank you for the clarification, there is a subtle difference. It's especially difficult for me because English is my second language. Would you mind adding your answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 3):

"Inside of the window" refers to an interior space. "On the inside of the window" refers to an interior surface.

Comment: To clarify: it's a real problem if you get condensation _inside_ a _double-pane window_, because you cannot get rid of it!